# checkBox in gridView doesn't update my table

Tags: c#

I am using the following the code to populate table on clicking upon the checkbox but there is no change in table

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chkUpdate = (CheckBox)
      GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect");
            if (chkUpdate != null)
            {
                if (chkUpdate.Checked)
                {
                    string strID = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                    SqlCommand cmd;
                    string str1 = "update app1 set p_id=0 where p_id='" + strID + "'";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
                    cmd .ExecuteNonQuery ();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Uh...what's your question again? First, I don't see a question mark. Second, I fail to see how this code relates to filling the `DataGridView`.

Comment: What is the data type of `p_id`?

Comment: @boby and kael i am having a table with name app1(two columns 'nam' and 'p_id' p_id is of int type)..at front end i am using checkbox inside gridview and on clicking on checkbox when user finally click to button..a change should be reflect back to table

Comment: Try removing the single quotes in your query.. Instead of `string str1 = "update app1 set p_id=0 where p_id='" + strID + "'";`, use `string str1 = "update app1 set p_id=0 where p_id=" + strID;`

Comment: @kael i am sorry i did not work out

Comment: beware of sql injection.

Comment: where this sql injection came from ...i am doing this code on my pc and the code is not affecting the database

Comment: I agree with Mubashir Khan, why don't you use Stored procedures? And have you already tried debugging your code?

Comment: yes i tried with debugging..and this is the simple sql command so why should i go for stored procedures

Comment: check the content of strID.. maybe could be some extra HTML tag inside that invalidate the id....

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it works

```
foreach (GridViewRows gdrv in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkUpdate = (CheckBox)
  gdrv.FindControl("chkSelect");
        if (chkUpdate != null)
        {
            if (chkUpdate.Checked)
            {
                string strID = gdrv.Cells[1].Text;
                SqlCommand cmd;
                string str1 = "update app1 set p_id=0 where p_id='" + strID + "'";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
                con.open();
                cmd .ExecuteNonQuery ();
                con.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: with this code i am getting error 'gridview does not contain any defination for cells

Comment: what did u use in cells[1] is there any control

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate >
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk"  AutoPostBack ="false"  runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="p_id" HeaderText="p_id" SortExpression="p_id" />
 <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField ="nam" DataNavigateUrlFields ="nam" DataNavigateUrlFormatString ="hyperlink.aspx?nam={0}" HeaderText ="nam" /></Columns></asp:GridView>

Comment: your html is proper and i am sure above code should work on it

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you really don't have a space in `cmd .ExecuteNonQuery ();`

When debugging, can you step into the `if(chkUpdate.Checked)` block?

Comment: @adrianos cmd .ExecuteNonQuery is not an space it is question format issue

Comment: Can you debug that method? I.e if you put a breakpoint on it, does it find the checkbox?

Comment: Also, check if you are repopulating that grid in the page load. You probably only want to do it (repopulate from dB) when postback is false

Comment: yup i did..but did not get satisfactory answer

Comment: What does that mean? Your code steps into if(chkUpdate.Checked) code block?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem in the query is the "Where" condition... if the p_id is Int type then you don't have to use ''...

So the statement must be :

```
string str1 = "update app1 set p_id=0 where p_id=" + strID;
```